# Double-click to cut and then insert + shift when a new cell is clicked,

Tags: excel, vba

Apologies if this has been answered before, but event handling is still quite new to me.

What I'm trying achieve is to double-click on a cell to cut it to the clipboard, and then when I click on a new cell for the cut cell to be inserted at that point, shifting the existing cells down.

The double-click bit to cut the cell is easy enough:

```
Private Sub Worksheet_BeforeDoubleClick(ByVal Target As Range, Cancel As Boolean)

    Cancel = True
    Target.Cut

End Sub
```

... but the rest of it is not obvious to me given that it needs to call another event (SelectionChange I'm assuming) from within an event.

How is this achieved? I've done some searching -- and I'm sure it's going to be obvious -- but I'm probably not searching on the right terms.

Thanks in advance.

EDIT: Many thanks for the answer.

As the ever-popular follow-up question -- is there a way to accomplish the same thing when dragging a cell using the grab-the-border method: i.e. have the cell dragged and inserted rather than invoke the "do you want to replace" dialogue? I know this can be done by holding down the Shift key -- but I'm looking for a way to code a sheet so that a drag-and-dropped cell will insert automatically rather than overwrite.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How about this?

```
Private Sub Worksheet_BeforeDoubleClick(ByVal Target As Range, Cancel As Boolean)

    Cancel = True
    Target.Cut

End Sub

Private Sub Worksheet_SelectionChange(ByVal Target As Range)

    If Application.CutCopyMode = xlCut Then
        Target.Insert Shift:=xlDown
        Application.CutCopyMode = False
    End If

End Sub
```

Update:

There isn't a drag event for cells but a hacky workaround based on this link http://www.mrexcel.com/forum/excel-questions/284788-challenging-post-override-cell-drag-drop-behavior-2.html

This essentially allows the drag, then applies UNDO to find the target and destination cells. The only addition I've made is to add Application.AlertBeforeOverwriting to disable the overwrite message.

```
Dim trigger As Boolean
Dim flag As Boolean
Dim busy As Boolean
Const overwriteAlert As Boolean = False


Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)

    With Target
        If .Count = 1 And trigger Then
            If flag Then
            If busy Then Exit Sub
            busy = True
            Call MyDrag
            flag = False
            Else
            flag = True
            End If
        End If
    End With

End Sub

Private Sub Worksheet_SelectionChange(ByVal Target As Range)

    flag = False
    busy = False
    trigger = Target.Count = 1
    Application.AlertBeforeOverwriting = overwriteAlert

End Sub

Sub MyDrag()
Dim DragAddress As String
Dim DropAddress As String

    With Application
    .EnableEvents = False
    .ScreenUpdating = False

    DropAddress = ActiveCell.Address
    .Undo
    DragAddress = ActiveCell.Address

        If Range(DropAddress).Column = Range(DragAddress).Column Then
        .Undo
        Else

            With Range(DropAddress)
            .Activate
            .Insert Shift:=xlDown
            .Offset(-1) = Range(DragAddress)
            End With

        Range(DragAddress).Delete Shift:=xlUp
        End If

    .ScreenUpdating = True
    .EnableEvents = True
    End With

'busy = False

End Sub
```

Comment: That is exactly it. It was the proper If clause that wasn't coming to me - many thanks.

Comment: I've asked a follow-up via an edit in my original post - would appreciate if you could take a look at it.

Comment: Much appreciated again - a very comprehensive solution. I'll study the code as a learning exercise.